# Get common data present in df['num'] and df1['num'] and merge the data which is the same from both the data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, data-science

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [2, 4, 9, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'num': [2, 4, 6, 0, 8, 9],
                   'num_wing': [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen': [10, 2, 1, 8, 8, 8]})
```

These are the two data frames where, we need to find the common in df[num] and df1[num] and get all other columns related to it.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Common how? On what key? Which columns do you want? What outputs do you expect? Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner merge??

```
merged_df = df.merge(df1, on = 'num', how = 'inner')
```

OUTPUT:

```
   num  num_wings  num_specimen_seen  num_wing  num_specimen
0    2          2                 10         2            10
1    4          0                  2         0             2
2    9          0                  1         0             8
3    0          0                  8         0             8
```

Comment: I assume so too given the information posted.